container-type not working for element with auto/fit-content...Any workaround?
So just a background .. I am creating an application with good amounts of CSS Animations due to which my sites performance is reducing ... I want to use transform everywhere in my site so it performs better in various devices ..
I want to move my SVG to the middle of the parent element using cqw but unfortunately from what i have looked(Container Queries based on height not working) container-type only works with fixed dimensions(which defeats the entire purpose of having it)
So with any luck has anyone been able to create a workaround of this issue??
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:Arial;
}
.container{
  background-color:red;
  width:fit-content;
  height:fit-content;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
container-type:inline-size;
}
svg{
/*transform:translateX(calc(50cwq - 50%));*/
  width:100px;
  aspect-ratio:1;
}


<div class="container">
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 18 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="m-path" d="M2 19V1L9 14.9091L16 1V19" stroke="#EEEEEE" stroke-width="2.5"/>
  </svg>  
  <div>this is a very long text whos width i dont know</div>
</div>

codepen

It's not an issue but the main feature of container query. You need to understand how container query are designed to work

yeah the answer hereexplains how container-type works
i was actually on a hunt to figure out how to move element in the middle of an element using transform question and ended with cqw..but i think the flex-grow solution would be better in this case
